# Salesforce1 apple watch demo project issue

Tags: salesforce1-app, salesforce1-platform, salesforce1-applewatch

I have downloaded the demo project from [github](https://github.com/developerforce/SalesforceWear-DevPack-For-AppleWatch) that was referred in the salesforce1 developer website and I ran it to test the salesforce1 apple watch app. I'm not able to go pass the loading screen on the apple watch simulator. The console is also empty and doesn't show anything. Attached the [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akB9d.png).

[image]